# How to clean the other commits in Pull Request

Tags: github

https://github.com/Decimal458/test.git

[image]

When I create a PR(#3,#5,#7) to merge "dev/" into "stage", the PR include old commit.
[image]

But create PR(#4,#6,#8) to merge "dev/" into "main", it would not happend.
[image]

In the company I work for, those PRs that are merged into the "stage" may contain more commits and even see other people's files in "Files Changed".

I would like to know how to only display my own commits or files when creating a PR that is merged into stage, just like a PR that is merged into main.

Note: I don't have permission to execute merge in the company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know how to only display my own commits or files when creating a PR that is merged into stage, just like a PR that is merged into main.

This is all about `rebasing --onto`: you rebase only your commits on top of the PR target branch, and then force push your feature branch.

That will update the PR, and show only your own commits.

[image: rebase --onto]

If you were to make a PR from `CVG-xxx` to develop, you would see commits from `CVG-yyy`, because your feature branch was initially create from it.

Assuming CVG-yyy is the commit just before your own CVG-xxx branch:

```
git fetch
git rebase --onto origin/develop CVG-yyy CVG-xxx
git push --force
```

The result is: only your own commits are on top of `origin/develop` now.
Your PR (to origin/develop) will only include your commits.

Comment: I think this is equivalent to creating a new branch on the "stage". But I can't do this.
This process is defined by the work team.

Comment: @Erriorn No, same branch, but rebased.

Comment: I created a PR of branch-F that was incorporated into the stage, in which Files Changed included D1, F1~4
Then use `rebase --onto` to rebase F1~4 to origin/stage and give him a branch name (rebase-branch-F)
Final, create a PR of rebase-branch-F to stage, which only contains F1~4
Am I doing right?

Comment: @Erriorn If you have an existing PR with too many commits for the source branch, rebasing and force pushing that source branch will update the *existing* PR: no need to create a second PR.